# Apply z-index to bespoke js carousel plugin

Tags: html, css, z-index, css-transforms, bespoke.js

I am trying to implement a carousel using bespoke.js. The link to my codepen is [Link](https://codepen.io/asinha/pen/zZEOGj).

```
How do I apply z-index to the slides, which are not in focus? 
If I do z-index:1, then the whole orientation changes so, What should be done ?
```

Comment: As i understand you need only active slide was visible and other was hide?

Comment: no not hide, the background color is overlapping with the slides which are not in center. I just want to make that correct

Comment: @aayushi set position: relative to parent then set z-index at child. shold work

Comment: can you show a demo please, because when I do the same everything fades away @DanielH

Comment: @aayushi ok all your code at that codepen link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want? This allowed the next two img to show `opacity: 1`.
`.bespoke-active + .bespoke-inactive` will select the 1st inactive img after Active

`.bespoke-active + .bespoke-inactive + .bespoke-inactive` will select the 2nd inactive img after Active:

```
.bespoke-active + .bespoke-inactive,
.bespoke-active + .bespoke-inactive + .bespoke-inactive{
   opacity: 1;
}
```

LINK: https://codepen.io/hdl881127/pen/jmKpMB

#### UPDATE: A better approach:

Since your js lib will add those class to your section (img container), you can use them to target the img before Active and img after the Active one:

```
.bespoke-before-1,
.bespoke-before-2,
.bespoke-after-1,
.bespoke-after-2 {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

LINK: https://codepen.io/hdl881127/pen/QvxBxM

Comment: yes, thanks a lot !! are these inbuilt classes of bespoke js?

Comment: @aayushi I think so, I'm inspect those img and those are added by the lib you are using.

Comment: Hi @aayushi, I updated my answer, I found a better approach, it will deal better if you want img before the Active one to show full opacity as well. Since the lib you are using will add those class dynamically to the section. Should take advantage of that to target the img section.